# Read the last line of a CSV file and extract one value in Knime

Tags: knime

I am working in a workflow on Knime, and I have an excel writer node as a final node of my workflow. I need to read this file and get and store the last value of one specific column (time). And with this data, I need to input in another time node, to update my API link to get a new request.

To summarize I need to extract specific information from the last line of my excel file in knime.

My question is: How can I read this file and get this value from my sheet? And then, how can update a time loop to refresh the data for inserting the current day in my API link?[image]

**UDDATE-> My question is how can I Filter always the last 90 days in my concatenate database. I have two columns in this file with dates. And I need to maintain just the last 90 days since the current day.**

Comment: So the *Rule-based Row Filter* (node 707) is configured to include only rows where the date is later than 90 days ago? That should do what you want, as I understand it. Can you show an example of the output you get compared to what you want - with dummy data if the real data is too big to show or is confidential?

Answer (score 2):

To read an Excel file, use the [Excel Reader](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.ext.poi3.node.io.filehandling.excel.reader.ExcelTableReaderNodeFactory) node.

The simplest way to get the last row of a table (assuming your date column has a value for every row of this table?) is probably to use a [Rule-based Row Filter](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.rules.engine.RuleEngineFilterNodeFactory) with the expression

```
$$ROWINDEX$$ = $$ROWCOUNT$$ => TRUE
```

Now you have a one-row table with the values from the last line of the Excel sheet. To help further we need to understand what you mean by *update a time loop to refresh the date for inserting the current day in my API link*. Can you update your question with a screenshot of your current KNIME code?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. I tried another way. What I need is always keep that last 90 days filtered in my excel file. I constructed from the API link, and every day I run my workflow to get the current day, and with the concatenate node, I assemble the last data plus the current day. But I always need to keep just the last 3 months, So I used the Excel Reader node, and with date&time shift I filter the last 90 days. My question is how can I filter my concatenate file based on the output of date&time shift (last 90 days)?